# Passing touches and vertical scrolling through horizontal UIScrollView (iOS 6)

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I'm trying to add a support for a horizontal scrolling between views (let's call them "pages") previously accessed via a segmented control. The thing is, putting them as subviews to the scroll view is not easily achievable due to a rather complex hierarchy and animations already in place.

Instead, the scroll view is used as an invisible overlay for those pages. When moved, its (also invisible) subviews are used to determine the frames of pages. So far, so good. But scroll view steals all the touches! Even vertical scrolling, which every single page supports, is lost.

I have tried fiddling with `hitTest:withEvent:` and `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, `touchesMoved:withEvent:`, `touchesEnded:withEvent:` with no helpful outcome.

Is there any way to let `UIScrollView` handle horizontal scrolling, but pass through vertical one and all the non-scrolling/swiping touches? The only option I'd rather not to go, is by subclassing `UIWindow` to send touch events directly to whoever listens to them. (seems like an overkill to me with a hackish feeling) The solution must be working for iOS 6.0.

Thank you.